# Conditional statement with three condition

Tags: conditional-tags

I am trying to write an if condition with 3 statements but it keeps crashing the site. Here is my statement, can you please advise what the issue is.

```
<?php if (is_page ('20')){?>
print this
<?php elseif (is_page ('50')){?>
then print this
<?php } else { ?>
print this
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `}` before `elseif`:

```
<?php if (is_page ('20')){?>
print this
<?php } elseif (is_page ('50')){?>
then print this
<?php } else { ?>
print this
<?php } ?>
```

Remove the PHP tags and you'll see why:

```
if ( is_page( '20' ) ) {

elseif ( is_page( '50' ) ) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks you , this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may write the statement in only one, short row:

```
print (is_page('20') ? "my output for page 20" : (is_page('50') ? "my output for page 50" : "my output for anything else") );
```

Important: Brackets must be in the right order like `(statement ? if-result : else-result)` where the "else-result" is a 2nd nested statement, so it looks like `(statement-1 ? 1st-if-result : (statement ? 2nd-if-result : last-else-result) )`
Good luck!